# SQL business minutes between two datetimes

Tags: sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I want to create a function in MS SQL server 2008 or higher that calculates the business minutes between two datetimes. I have tested 20+ answers found here and on other sites and cant yet find one that works consistently. The start and and end times of the business are 08:30 and 17:30. I ask for the difference between 2016-10-09 18:35 and 2016:-11-09 9:00. That is Sept 10th 6:45PM and Sept 11th 9AM. I expect to get back 30 minutes, but they all return 0. I really dont want to loop minute by minute checking each minute, just some basic SQL "math".

Comment: Can you just post the query you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL can be converted into 1 function or keep them as two separate.  Personally, I think keeping them separate is more useful.  You'll have fewer touch-points and can server multiple masters.

In the Business Minutes function, I added an option/illustration to exclude Weekends and/or Holidays.   Simply remove if not necessary.

The Date-Range function is used to generate dynamic date ranges.  It is much faster than the recursive cte approach.

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2016-09-10 18:35','2016-09-11 9:00')
```

Returns

```
30
```

**The Business Minute Function**

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes] (@D1 Datetime,@D2 Datetime)
Returns int
Begin
    Return (
            Select Minutes=count(*)
             From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](case when @D1<=@D2 then @D1 else @D2 end,case when @D1<=@D2 then @D2 else @D1 end,'MI',1)
             Where Cast(RetVal as time) between '08:31' and '17:30'
               and RetVal >case when @D1<=@D2 then @D1 else @D2 end
               and DatePart(DW,RetVal) not in (7,1)  
               and Cast(RetVal as Date) not in (Select Date from (Values 
                                                  ('2016-01-01','New Year''s Day'),
                                                  ('2016-01-18','Martin Luther King, Jr,'),
                                                  ('2016-02-15','Washington''s Birthday'),
                                                  ('2016-03-25','Good Friday'),
                                                  ('2016-05-30','Memorial Day'),
                                                  ('2016-07-04','Independence Day'),
                                                  ('2016-09-05','Labor Day'),
                                                  ('2016-11-24','Thanksgiving'),
                                                  ('2016-11-25','Black Friday'),
                                                  ('2016-12-26','Christmas Day')
                                                  ) as Holidays (Date,Name)
                                              )   
    )
End
```

**The Generic Date Range Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

> **EDIT - Made a small adjustment to allow for multiple days changed 8:30 to 8:31 to avoid double count **

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2016-09-10 05:00','2016-09-10 19:00')
```

Returns 540

While (spanning two days)

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2016-09-10 05:00','2016-09-11 19:00')
```

Returns 1080

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2015-12-31 12:30','2016-01-03 11:30:00')  --Returns 300
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2016-09-30 05:00','2016-09-30 19:00:00')  --Returns 540
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2016-09-29 05:00','2016-09-30 19:00:00')  --Returns 1080
Select [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes]('2015-12-31 12:30','2016-01-03 11:30:00')  --Returns 300
```

Comment: This appears to be the solution. One thing to check, start date should not be earlier than end date or an error "A TOP N value may not be negative" is thrown. I uncommented the test for Saturday & Sunday & that works also. One thing I am confused with... Testing with the holidays "Select dbo.udf-Business-Minutes('12/31/2015 12:30', '1/3/2016 11:30')" returns 301 minutes? The 300 minute on the 31st and 180 on the third should be 480?

Comment: @Ricardo Updated this answer.  Added "and RetVal >@D1" .. small tweak.  Also the 180 is either a Sat/Sun.

Comment: @Ricardo Regarding the Date Order Trap..  Do you want 0 minutes if the sequence is wrong, or would you like the logic to flip them if necessary?

Comment: @Ricardo Updated the answer so it does not matter the order of dates  (trap built into udf-Business-Minutes only.  I won't sacrifice performance in the dynamic date range function.

Comment: I am going to mark this as an accepted answer, but, if I use this in a Select query - Select field, field, [dbo].[udf-Business-Minutes](date1, date2) from table) The performance on a 100+ records is not good.

Comment: @Ricardo I'll noodle it a bit more to see if I can improve performance.  Just curious how long on 100+ records?

Comment: @Ricardo I just generated a random sample of 365 records and the response time was 0.595 seconds (on my laptop, not my server).  181 records was 0.204 seconds.

Comment: OK thanks. I am certain have a sql instance issue, since 530 records returns the values in NINE seconds!

Comment: @Ricardo Ooof!  My laptop is 3 years old, I would be happy to sell it to you cheap. :)